# Facebook publish_action

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm having a strange problem. I'm developing an integration of facebook inside my app. I managed to make it works, with login and publish_actions so I can post as user inside my app. To open a page I use this code

```
session.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(getActivity()).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("read_stream", "publish_stream", "publish_actions", "email", "manage_pages")).setCallback(callback));
```

The session was opened and with a right token created.
I don't know why but,  2 weeks ago, the company for which I am working changed the APP_ID of the app inside the developer app page of facebook, and now I have a bad issue : **when I use the same code to use the login, in the login popup**

https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t39.2178-6/10173501_712654372111832_803467338_n.png

with specificed **This not let the app post to Facebook**

I contact the company and we have done the following steps on the developer page

1. App Detail > Configure app center permissions > **Added publish action permissions**
2. Settings > add platform **Added android platform with name of my app package**

The app is not in developer mode, it's public. The problem is still there What can be the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: First you need  to review your app by Facebook check bottom part of your apps setting page

Answer (score 1):

You have to submit your app to facebook for review. Previously there is no need to submit app to facebook but now you must.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Visit above link, which shows step by step process for submit your app to app store.